# Upgrading to Spring Boot Mongodb 2.2.X hides GeoNear Aggregate pipeline results past 100 records

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a paginated API backed by an `Aggregation` with a `$geoNear` pipeline step. 
In Mongo versions before `4.2`, `$geoNear` aggregations had a default limit of 100.

To avoid this, it was possible to set the `num` field to a large number for the NearQuery.

```
    Query query = new Query();
    ...
    NearQuery nearQuery = NearQuery.near(...);
    nearQuery.query(query);

    //force the geoNear operation to return more than 100 results
    nearQuery.num(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    List<AggregationOperation> steps = Lists.newArrayList(geoNear(nearQuery, "distance"));
    //add skip and limit operations to mimic pagination functionality
    steps.add(skip(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize()));
    steps.add(limit(pageable.getPageSize()));

    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(steps);
    ...
```

In Mongo version `4.2`, the `num` field has been removed as well as the limit of 100 results (described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) in the first note). In response to this, `GeoNearOperation.java` has been [updated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/bcefdd209bc98f21986d5263c518461e49a58788/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/GeoNearOperation.java#L123) in `spring-data-mongodb` to remove the `num` field.

Now, I would understand that if I were to connect to a MongoDb server running version `4.2` everything would work as is (disclaimer: I have not tried this.) However, I'm running version `4.0.5` locally and version `3.6.12` in production. Using `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` with version `2.1.13.RELEASE` the above code works and paginated results are returned past 100 results. Upgrading to `2.2.0.RELEASE` causes the above `Aggregation` to no longer return past 100 results.

How am I supposed to query a MongoDB database on a version older than `4.2` with the `2.2.X` branch of 
`spring-data-mongodb` if the `num` field is always removed?

Comment: The [GeoNearOperation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/eacfe2b8f70ae5d4b70aa6c17612825278330400/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/GeoNearOperation.java#L133) already adds `$skip` and `$limit` stages to the pipeline. Did you try removing the manually added additional steps?

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I tried removing those steps and still can't get past 100 records. With the MongoTemplate and Query logging levels set to DEBUG, I can see $limit and $skip added at the end of the pipeline. When run against an older version of Mongo, the $geoNear part is still restricted by the 100 default records without the num field

Comment: Looking at the `geonear` [source for 3.6](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/31624e095b163379dd95e0c29b44f2a9e412f8fd/src/mongo/db/commands/geo_near_cmd.cpp#L189) limit is hard coded to 100 without a server option to configure. Only way is to set `num` via the command. We need to see if there's something we can do on Spring Data side. Created [DATAMONGO-2524](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2524) for this.

Comment: Thank you @ChristophStrobl. To be clear, I'm seeing this behavior on version 4.0.5 as well and suspect it would be the same for anything under 4.2

Comment: A solution working for 4.2+ and pre 4.2 servers would require knowledge about the server version, which is not present. We cannot simply re-add the `num` argument because 4.2+ servers reject the query if present. Maybe overriding `GeoNearOperation.toPipelineStages` with `return Collections.singletonList(toDocument(context));` is an option for you? 
Please feel free to continue the discussion about potential alternatives in the [issue tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2524).

Answer (score -1):

yes try using mongoTemplate. It should work

```
Point point = new Point(51.4678685, -0.0860632);
List<Pub> venues =
            mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("location").near(point).maxDistance(0.01)), Pub.class);
```

further refer
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Comment: This won't work because it doesn't return the calculated 'distance' field. The entire point of this post is the use of Aggregation, not just a plain Query